# How to remove border from Country flag nad code intel-tel?

Tags: css

I am sing intel-tel library for mobile number. I have issue to remove black border on country code it appear when i click on it
[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `outline: none;` on the element which is having that black outline.

Comment: Actually I am back-end developer 